# "Convert to edit" option for subsequent answer from the same user needed

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

There are significant number of times where a user provides a second answer rather than editing their first. [This question on Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40817/youtube-videos-posted-to-facebook/) is the most recent I have come across (diamonds or 10k users only can see the deleted answer).

In cases like this there's only so much we can currently do:

1. Leave a comment in the hope that the OP will be bothered enough to come back and edit the first answer.
2. Edit the contents of the second answer into the first ourselves and delete the second answer.

It would be far simpler if we had something analogous to the "convert to edit" option that exists for converting answers from the questioner into edits on the question.

So if there are multiple answers from the same user please enable the "convert to edit" option.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea.  But I would suggest the name "Merge with question".

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - I don't want to merge with the question (I can already do that if the OP posts an answer). This is about merging two **answers** from the same user.